# Is there no way to insert to an STL list in O(1) time?

Tags: c++, list, stl

Theoretically, you should be able to insert anywhere into a list (at the index of your choosing) in O(1) time. But, when using STL list, you need to insert at the iterator position and to my understanding the iterator position has to be incremented O(n) times to set it to the index you want. I am dumbfounded as to why this is the way it is, surely I am mistaken and there is a way to do it faster?

Comment: Lists don't really have indexes.   Your understanding of a list seems to be fundamentally flawed.  Perhaps you want a `std::vector`?

Comment: A `std::list` is a double linked list. Traversing to the Nth element is `O(N)` like any other linked list. If you already have an iterator to the position you want to insert a new element at, then it's `O(1)`.

Comment: No, you have misunderstood (it's a common misunderstanding, though). With a linked list, you can insert at a given *node*'s position in constant time. Determining that node takes linear time on average.

Comment: It may help resolve your confusion if you try to code yourself a list with the type of insertion you want. You will get stuck at some point, and that exact point will be the answer to your question.

Comment: "Insertion in a linked list is a constant-time operation" seems to be one of those mantras that you learn early in your career, just before forgetting the conditions under which it is true.You can find a recent video of Stroustrup online, where he shares his surprise over how slow random list insertions are compared to a vector.

Comment: Another nasty surprise is under the wrong conditions O(1) can be more time consuming than a worse time complexity. For example, poor caching behaviour or unpredictable flow can massacre what otherwise looks like a great idea. Profile and make sure reality backs up your expectations.

Comment: The aforementioned Stroustrup discussion on linked lists (including link to video) : https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists

Answer (score 5):

> surely I am mistaken

No, you are not mistaken.

> and there is a way to do it faster?

You can do it faster only if you have cached the postion at which to insert by capturing the return value from a previous call to insert. If you have no information other than a list and an index at which you wish to insert, then `O(n)` is your only option where `n` is the index at which you wish to insert.